# .Net : multiple keys to list of values

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, data-structures, key-value

I am looking for data structure or optimized code snippet which helps me to store multiple keys mapping to a list of string values and also how efficiently we can access list values using any one of the key from multiple keys pool.

Let me put these in a sample example. say keys are `"Hi, "Hello", "how are you ?"` maps to VALUES `"1234", "56789", "34567"`

now is it possible for me to fetch the VALUES list (all 3 elements) using any one of the keys like "Hi" or "Hello" or "how are you ?" in a single statement.

I am trying to avoid looping through the keylist to match the key.

Comment: If you have 3 keys, looping is by far the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>` where the different keys that map to the same list share the same reference of the list.

For your example above:

```
var values = new List<string> { "1234", "56789", "34567" };
var mapping = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    ["Hi"] = values,
    ["Hello"] = values,
    ["how are you ?"] = values
};
```

Then accessing through the indexer will retrieve the same reference for all those keys (`mapping["Hi"] == mapping["Hello"]`).

---

If you have your data in the form of a list of keys and values then you can use the following to create the flattened dictionary for it:

```
var rawData = new List<(List<string> keys, List<string> values)>
{
    (new List<string> {"Hi", "Hello", "how are you ?" }, new List<string> {"1234", "56789", "34567" })
};

var result = rawData.SelectMany(item => item.keys.Select(k => (k, item.values)))
                    .ToDictionary(key => key.k, val => val.values);
```

*Note that for ease of writing I used the named tuples of C# 7.0. Of course it can be also done with custom classes or with anonymous types in the linq part*

See that when constructing the data structure it does look through all the keys so it is still an `O(n)` operation but then accessing a value using any of the keys is an `O(1)` operation.